# Create a custom field on WooCommerce checkout if product category equals x

Tags: woocommerce

so I'm looking to create/show a couple of custom fields on the checkout page of my WooCommerce page as long as a product with a certain category is in the cart. The values of these fields are only necessary for me to access in the order on the backend afterwards, and does not need to be added to the order e-mail confirmation to the customer.

Any pointers? If it helps things, I'm using ACF on my website.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. Detect if the existing products in cart is in your category
2. Add the fields on checkout if it matches your condition.
3. Validate and save the data
4. Display it on the backend.

This is already outlined on the docs, and you might want to read it:
https://woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#adding-a-custom-special-field

Here is an example function to detect if the cart contains a certain product within a defined category

```
// functions.php

function cat_in_cart( $cat_slug ) {
    $cat_in_cart = false;
    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    if ( !$cart ) {
        return $cat_in_cart;
    }
    foreach( $cart as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if ( has_term( $cat_slug, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] )) {
            $cat_in_cart = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $cat_in_cart;
}
```

To add a field on checkout ([Link to docs](https://woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)):

```
// functions.php
/**
 * Add the field to the checkout
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    if ( cat_in_cart( 'your_category_slug' ) ) {

        echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('My Field') . '</h2>';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Fill in this field'),
            'placeholder'   => __('Enter something'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));

        echo '</div>';
    }

}
```

After that, save the field on checkout:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['my_field_name'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter something into this new shiny field.' ), 'error' );
}
```

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['my_field_name'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'My Field', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['my_field_name'] ) );
    }
}
```

Lastly, display it on the dashboard:

```
/**
 * Display field value on the order edit page
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('My Field').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'My Field', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! First of all, theres an error on the line which start with "If ( has_term(..". The end parenthesis should not come after $cat_slug, but after $cart_item['product_id']. Also it didnt show up immediatly, but thats because I have disabled order_notes - so the _after_order_notes hook doesnt work for me. Changed this to woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form. BUT: How do I see the value the customers put into this field? Ive added an order now, but cant see my new custom field in the order backend. I need the value of these fields to be shown when I view the order @ backend.

Comment: @SAH Updated answer. You need to validate, save and display the data. Also please read the docs https://woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#adding-a-custom-special-field